# Is there an open-source equivalent to Amazon SNS?

Tags: open-source, amazon-sns

Does anyone know of an open-source equivalent to Amazon SNS? Maybe something that supports a similar pub-sub interface but that can be run on a closed or private network.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are looking for a ready to install packaged solution? There is none I know of, however, in case you are comfortable with assembling some readily available components with a modest amount of custom code, you could build yourself a dedicated solution by means of the extremely versatile [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) framework, which *is a powerful open source integration framework based on known [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)*.

It includes [an ever growing list of components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) out of the box to interface with existing tools/protocols/APIs/etc., e.g. for cloning the *Amazon SNS* functionality:

- [Mail Component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html) - *provides access to Email via Spring's Mail support and the underlying JavaMail system*
- [HTTP4 Component](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) - *provides HTTP based endpoints for consuming external HTTP resources (as a client to call external servers using HTTP)*
- [SMPP Component](http://camel.apache.org/smpp.html) - *provides access to an SMSC (Short Message Service Center) over the SMPP protocol to send and receive SMS*
- AWS Components - even those are available, in case you'd like to use them as well still

  - [SNS Component](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sns.html) - *For Messaging with [Amazon's Simple Notification Service (SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) service*
  - SQS Component - *For Messaging with [Amazon's Simple Queue Service (SQS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs) service*

Assembling the components is remarkably simple indeed, and there are lots of [Examples](http://camel.apache.org/examples.html) available, see for example the walkthroughs for configuration [via Spring DSL (XML based)](http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-another-example.html) or [via Java code](http://camel.apache.org/walk-through-an-example.html)

Granted, assembling a decently performing and scaling system like so will still require a fair amount of knowledge, but *Apache Camel* at least removes the burden regarding many of the involved tasks already.

Answer (score 2):

Realize this question is a little old, but came across this recently:

http://www.slideshare.net/openstack/open-source-versions-of-amazons-sns-and-sqspptx

Comment: interesting, though I am not sure I want to use anything written by Comcast ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Java Message Service, aka JMS, a message oriented middleware